# Is posting a tip considered self-promotion?

Tags: discussion

Related to:

[How can I make the font larger on Ancestry.com trees?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/how-can-i-make-the-font-larger-on-ancestry-com-trees)

I posted a CSS tweak for increasing the font size of Ancestry.com's trees, and was summarily down-voted.

I don't have any stake in either the Chrome/Firefox extension mentioned (which is freeware) or the custom stylesheet (which is also free released it into the public domain). I created the tweak for myself and thought some other Ancestry users might find it useful.

Yet, one moderator claims I'm self-promoting by posting this. I'm new here, but I'm an old hat at Stack Overflow, I know the general rules on SE properties, and I don't consider this post to be spammy at all.

Answer (score 3):

My first take on reading your question over in Main was "looks like possible self promotion" so I can understand where @AmericanLuke and at least one other are/were coming from.  However, having an interest in web and desktop software developers providing better control on font size Out Of The Box, and being a heavy Ancestry.com user, I read more carefully and recognised it as a similar issue to one over at [**GIS Stack Exchange Meta**](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/change-the-design-of-the-ask-question-button/3266#3266).

Had you been receiving revenue for downloads of your **custom style for Ancestry.com** (to use with the free **Stylish** browser extension) I would stick with my initial impression, but that certainly does not appear to be the case, and so I view your Q&A contribution to be an altruistic and valuable one.

Also, I note your very impressive **[StackOverflow body of work](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16306/richardtallent)** and am hoping that you will continue to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange is a Q&A platform, designed for question and answer based content. People ask questions and get answers. However, when someone asks a question without the intention of getting an answer, it comes across as simple self-promotion.

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam.

Your answer wasn't spam per se, but the fact that you're simply pushing your extension (not really a tip) can trigger a negative reaction from some users.

Comment: As a side note (not saying you were doing this), this a very common spam technique. A user asks a question and immediately answers it with a spam answer linking to their product.

Comment: Answering your own question, even to convey something you already know the answer to, is explicitly ENCOURAGED on the SE Network. Please see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
The stated goals of SE, from Jeff and Joel, is more about building content that *future* visitors can refer to, it's not merely about answering individual, one-off questions.

Comment: As for "pushing my extension," again, it's not my extension. I only used that extension to write a CSS file to make Ancestry more useful to me, and thought someone else might also enjoy it. I gain no benefit from anyone else using it. As for "common spam techniques," your argument might be valid if I were actually linking to spam. But I wasn't, as anyone could easily verify. By that argument, *anyone* sharing a link to somewhere else on the 'Net could be labeled a potential spammer.

Answer (score 1):

Your participation in this site is in its early days, and I very much hope it continues.

The Q&A referred to very properly disclose your affiliation (developer of the style) even though you aren't (as it turns out) mentioning a commercial product. They provide a workaround for some of Ancestry's deficiencies that some people might find useful.

However, as PolyGeo said [here](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/104), on first sight it does look like self-promotion -- it isn't explicit in the answer that the solution is free, and not everybody will be inclined to do the work to find that out.

One thing I *don't* like about the question (and the reason I down-voted) was the solicitation in the answer for requirements to further develop the style:

> I'll continue tweaking it over time, so if you have any suggestions, I'm open to them.

Requests for requirements for software development have been definitely off-topic here in the past, although we're still feeling our way about which software development topics might be on-topic (at [Should we allow questions on developing genealogy software and websites?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/104))

Comment: If @richardtallent removed that request for requirements (I had overlooked them but am inclined to agree with you) would you think that grounds to change from a down to upvote?

Comment: @PolyGeo, not sure I'd upvote but I would remove the downvote.

Comment: Anytime I have tried to undo a -1 vote I thought it went to +1 rather than allowing a neutral 0

Comment: @PolyGeo As far as I know it undownvotes rather than upvotes.

Comment: I wonder if this is SE site-specific so will take note next time I do it in GFH and GIS SE sites.

Comment: I can see that point, so I've removed any solicitation for comments or mention of future improvements. I think given the data-centric nature of this hobby, some software-related questions *should* be allowed for developers engaging genealogists, but they should follow the same guidelines as other questions, i.e., something where an answer can be chosen as "most correct," not open-ended suggestion boxes.

Comment: I also added a few words to explicitly state that I'm not the developer of the Chrome/Firefox extension, I only wrote the stylesheet.